# Does ChartJS supports Jquery 3.4.1

Tags: chart.js

I cant get the version of Jquery that supports ChartJs. I updated my Jquery and suddenly charts does not show up. My current ChartJs version is 2.6.0.

In Developer Tools > Console I am  getting the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'arc' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-75) is negative.

Comment: I updated my ChartJs from 2.6.0 to 2.9.3 and it worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

As per the official docs it's not mentioned. [Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/)

You can check this using-

`$ === jQuery`

**OR**

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}
```